# Object reference not set to an instance of an object, on SqlConnection.Open(), asp.net

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sql

just learning asp.net with c# and my code is throwing this exception when im trying to open a connection to my database:

```
string connectionString ="DataSource=localhost,3306;Database=somedatabase;Uid=username;Pwd=password;";
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    con.Open(); // Exception Thrown Here
}
```

Seems relatively simple, so ive really no clue why this is happening.

one other thing;

all this code is inside  tags on the webpage (not really sure if that makes any difference, quite new to asp.net)

Cheers!

edit-

Hey, here is the rest of it.
Im going to investigate habib's solution.

I am missing some assemblies (mysql), but ill get back when ive tried it out.

```
<%@ Language=C# %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="MySql" %>

<HTML>
   <script runat="server" language="C#">
   void MyButton_OnClick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

   }

        void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
           {
                // GET THE USERNAME AND PASSWORD FROM THE CLIENT
                NameValueCollection nvc = Request.Form;

                string username = nvc["username"];
                string password = nvc["password"];
                Login(username, password);
           }

           void Login(string username, string password)
           {
                string connectionString = "Data Source=localhost,3306;Database=something;Uid=somename;Pwd=somepass;";
                using(MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    con.Open();
    /*
                if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                    return;

                try
                {
                    SqlDataReader   reader = null;
                    SqlCommand      command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username=@username AND password=@password", con);

                    reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    Response.Write(reader[0]);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Response.Write(e.ToString());
                }

                con.Close();*/
        }
        }
```

Comment: Is that really all your code?

Comment: Can you post more of your code?

Comment: I try to create a SqlConnection with this connectionstring and return this error "There is no support for the keyword: 'datasource'."

Comment: No, but I figured Id just post the problematic part :P

Comment: Just looking at your snippet above, what really stood out to me was the comma in your connection string after localhost. make sure your connection string is well formed: http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to open MySQL database connection through `SqlConnection`, Use `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection`

[`SqlConnection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx) class is used for SQL Server connection.

Comment: Does not explain the nullref exception.

Comment: @usr, I guess its because the OP is specifying a MySQL Connection string, the constructor for `SqlConnection` is returning `null`, hence the object `con` is null, BUT I am not sure about it.

Comment: A ctor never returns null, and the BCL should never crash internally. Very rare.

Comment: Seeing the updated comment by the OP, this is likely to be the solution. He probably has other funky stuff in his code that is not visible.